# A(nother) No-Sensa Test Question

Tags: pattern, visual, rebus, progressive-matrix

Which one of the five options (A to E) fits in the blank space? Why?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is:

> **E** - the larger 'U A U'.

Why? Because:

> Each rectangle displays the **vowels from the name of a major body in our solar system**. Specifically, starting top left and going clockwise, we see the vowels from the **eight planets** in order, going around the central rectangle containing the vowel from the **Sun**!
>
>  Moreover, the relative size of the letters in each box roughly represents the relative sizes of these bodies (not to scale).
>
>  In other words, we have (going clockwise):
>
>  M**E**RC**U**RY, V**E**N**U**S, **EA**RTH, M**A**RS, J**U**P**I**T**E**R, S**A**T**U**RN, ???, N**E**PT**U**N**E**.

What's missing?

> **U**R**A**N**U**S! i.e. '**U A U**'. Considering the two sizes available, we need to take the one more similar in size to Neptune (E U E) rather than the one close in size to Earth (EA) - i.e. option E.
>
>  (Also note that when vowels appear consecutively in a name - e.g. in '**EA**rth' - the letters appear next to each other without a space in this rebus. This is another reason to choose the more 'gappy' 'U A U' over the consecutive-appearing 'UAU' option in A...)

Comment: naq gura gurer vf gur pyhr nobhg --oynax fcnpr-- unun